Retrieving string through Ajax in .net 8 Web Application not working if string is 4096 characters or more
I am using Ajax to retrieve a chart that is about 65,000 bytes in base64 from a controller with:
ReturnResult ret = new() { Error = "" };

using var ms = new MemoryStream();
ChrtGraph.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
ret.Img = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    
return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(ret)

and this class:
public class ReturnResult
{ 
    public string? Img { get; set; }
    public required string Error { get; set; } = "";
}

and this ajax call:
var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm'),
    token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val(),
    GetTextureChart = {};

GetTextureChart.Width = 943;
GetTextureChart.Height = 466;

$.ajax({
    url: "Chart/GetTextureChart",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(GetTextureChart)),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        RequestVerificationToken: $(token).val()
    },
    success: function (response) {
        var ret = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
        
        if (ret.Error == "")
            $("#chrtgraph").attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + ret.Img);
        else
            $("#lblerr").text("Error " + ret.Error);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        $("#lblerr").text("fail " + response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        $("#lblerr").text("Error " + response.responseText);
    }
});

If the string from ret is more than 4095 bytes, it fails.  In the olden days, you could add a setting to web.config:
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000" />
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>

but there is no web.config file now.
I have looked all over and found various things such as adding to program.cs:
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = 100000;
});

but nothing works.  Is there a way to get a larger image with an ajax call?
A workaround:
I found something that will work.  If you add a
@page "{handler?}"

to the razor page, then add in somepage.cshtml.cs:
public JsonResult OnGetGetChart()
{
    ReturnResult ret = new() { Img = "", Id = [], Error = "" };

    // Bunch of other stuff

    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    ChrtGraph.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
    ret.Img = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

    return new JsonResult(ret);
}

you can then use:
$.get("/somepage/GetChart).done(function (img) {
    var ret = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(img));

    if (ret.error == "")
        $("#chrtgraph").attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + ret.img);
    else
        $("#lblerr").text("Error " + ret.Error);
}); 

and that works fine.  You do have to return a JsonResult rather than a string.  Don't get any weird flickering or other noticeable problems.  You have to use $.get though, an Ajax call doesn't work.  As a side note,  $.get changes the json to lower case.  What's that all about?
This page is eventually going to need authorization so I don't know what that will do but this does work.

Do you get any errors in network tab? Does data come correctly to front end? or you getn an exception? what problems are you facing exactly?

No, the success function just doesn't get called (neither do error or fail) if Img is more than 3099 bytes.  The same thing happened with the old asp pages and modifying web.config fixed it.

I edited the post.  It's the length of the Json string that can't be over 4095 characters.

If I try to return a JsonResult, that fails too.
